# Rules regarding 尊敬語 through history

Tags: grammar, sonkeigo

I'm reading a story that takes place like 30 years ago, which I think could be the only possible explanation of what I'm going ask. I often see this structure : Verb stem+ になられる as below:

> これほどの大勢で書斎を物色したなど、当主様が知られたらどれほど**お怒りになられる**ことか

However, it seems that japanese people pretty much all agree on the fact that this is a wrong usage of 尊敬語. Does that mean that although it was accepted before, it is not anymore? Or was it always considered as wrong?

Comment: Could you teach me about story's name?

Comment: @Rohan 「題名を教えてください」っておっしゃりたかったんだと思うんですが多分通じないです。「名前を教えてください」「電話番号を教えてください」と​かの「教える」は teach じゃなくて tell です。(teach は学問や技術を教えます) "Could you tell us the title of the story" みたいな感じでどうでしょう。

Comment: @Chocolate まさにその通りです...。教えてくださり有難うございます。きちんと英語を勉強してから書き込むようにします。☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

二重敬語 is grammatically correct. Since Japanese language began to be recorded in somewhat forms, there have been no periods when people ceased to use it. When something has used since old time and is still used today, you don't call it ungrammatical.

On the other hand, there's misconception even among native speakers that it's ungrammatical due to an administrative document that says 一般的に適切でないとされる (generally considered not decent). In my opinion, however, this meant that you should avoid use overly polite expressions in public speech for the sake of kind of political correctness (otherwise it wouldn't make sense because it was once officially used for imperial family member). In private speech, it's irrelevant to begin with.

Comment: `二重敬語 is grammatically correct.`  I would **LOVE** to see some support of this claim.

Comment: Me too. But it seems not so. Anyway, I'll stick to what's rational.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is called [二重敬語]{に・じゅう・けい・ご}.  It is grammatically incorrect, but sometimes/often(?) used.  As with any language, what is "wrong" and "accepted" evolves over time; varies by location, people groups; etc.  (e.g., "irregardless" in English).

But technically it is incorrect.  [Here is a quick reference](http://japanesekeigo.webnode.jp/keigo/questions/nijuukeigo-double-keigo/) for this pattern, but there are many other types of 二重敬語 as well (research left to the reader).